# HOW TO: Change datagridview LinkColumn Text when clicked

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewlinkcolumn

I'm having a problem in my `DataGridViewLinkColumn`. When specific `columnIndex` clicked, I want to change the link column text. *(please see example below)*
[image]

In example above, I want to change the text(the highlighted one) that is clicked to **SAVE**.
*NOTE: the changing must be done only in specific row and column index*

I used `datagridViewColumn` and here's my code: (link column displays when bind in datatable then display to datagrid.)

```
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DateReq AS [Date Requested],NoHrs AS [# OT Hrs.],status,approved_by FROM tableName" _
            & "WHERE requested_by='" & lbluserid.Text & "'" _
            & " ORDER BY date_request ASC", Constr)
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        ds.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)


        dg.DataSource = dt

        dg.Columns.Add(lnkEdit)
        lnkEdit.HeaderText = ""
        lnkEdit.Name = "edit"
        lnkEdit.Text = "Edit"
        lnkEdit.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True
        dg.Columns(4).Width = 45
        dg.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter

        dg.Columns.Add(lnkCancel)
        lnkCancel.HeaderText = ""
        lnkCancel.Name = "cancel"
        lnkCancel.Text = "Cancel"
        lnkCancel.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = True
        dg.Columns(5).Width = 45
        dg.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just handle the CellContentClick event, get the right cell and set it's value:

```
' If your DataGridView is named dataGridView1: '
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.CellContentClick
    dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "Saved"
End Sub
```

Note that your problem is that a `DataGridViewLinkCell` either displays it's `Value` (when `UseColumnTextForLinkValue == false`), or it displays the `Text` of it's `DataGridViewLinkColumn` (when `UseColumnTextForLinkValue == true`).

So if you want to change the text of the link at runtime you'll have to set `UseColumnTextForLinkValue = false`, and fill the cells beforehand with the text `Edit`, e.g. something like:

```
For Each row in dg.Rows
    row(your_link_column).Value = "Edit"
Next
```

Comment: thank you for your response but it's not working. I will update my above post. please see updated post.

Comment: I have only one datagrid in that form and I did double click the CellContentClick... but still it's not working.

Comment: I think you have to set `UseColumnTextForLinkValue` to `false`; otherwise, the value of the `Text` property is always displayed in each cell.

Comment: yes, I already did that but when I turn it to FALSE .. it has no value display its NULL..